# Multi-step form in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, json, session, codeigniter-3

```
Array
(
    [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1441951099
    [business_name] => Some
    [rental_description] => oppp's
    [session_data] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Super
            [last_name] => man
            [email_id] => super@gmail.com
            [password] => 123123
            [addressline1] => ll
            [addressline2] => dddd
            [phone] => 1231231234
            [country] => 1
            [state] => 2
            [zip] => 123456
        )

)
```

I have above array  which is result of multi-step form now i want above array data to be inserted in database.How can i achieve this?? My table structure is like below

```
camp_user_id
first_name
last_name
password
```

and so on

What i want to achieve i want the value of business_name to be inserted in business_name field ,first_name value in first_name field ,password value in password field and so on.Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the details of inserting from an array in the codeigniter documentation :
[CodeIngiter - Inserting data](http://file:///home/sunil/CI_300/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

```
$data = array(
    'camp_user_id' => $A['session_data']['rental_desc'],
    'first_name' => $A['session_data']['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $A['session_data']['last_name']
    ....)
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```